# How to add grid background Image in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wpf-controls

I am trying to change images source or image background in c# when a button is click with xaml design UI.

```
<Grid x:Name="gridimage">
            <Image x:Name="Image" stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid>

private void Button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     // NOT WORKING FOR ME
         gridimage.Source = new BitmapImage (new Uri("location"));
         gridimage.Background = ?
     }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete XAML and code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that there is an `Assets` folder in your Visual Studio project that contains an image file `2.png`, and that the image file's `Build Action` is set to `Resource`, you would create a BitmapImage in code behind from a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/2.png");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Then you would use the BitmapImage as `Source` of your Image control:

```
Image.Source = bitmap;
```

Or use it with an `ImageBrush` as `Background` of your Grid:

```
gridimage.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
```

Comment: how does this differ from my answer?

Comment: @Sajeetharan It shows the proper Pack URI syntax, and shows how to use *either* Image *or* ImageBrush, not both at the same time, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: OP was asking about how to set image in code behind, my answer does make sense

Comment: @Sajeetharan You acually do not show how to set the image in code behind, because (3rd time I tell you that) you do not show a Pack URI.

Comment: i was assuming that he will handle that, since i dont know the path when i posted the question. Certainly my answer don't deserve a downvote here.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Maybe you didn't realize, but there is no downvote on your answer (although it deserves one). In my opinion it is of absolutely no help to OP, which is also obvious from his comments.

Comment: @Sajeetharan How would you possibly know that?

Comment: What if you don't have a resource, but an image file on disk? (which you can't add at build time, so you must load it at runtime)